# Add Range to `IBInspectable` attribute

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

According to Apple docs, we can add these types to `IBInspectable` attribute.

[Render and inspect your custom views](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devf60c1c514)

> You can add the IBInspectable attribute to any property in a class declaration, class extension, or category of type: boolean, integer or floating point number, string, localised string, rectangle, point, size, colour, range, and nil.

I'm able to add all types except range. can somebody explain how to add range to `IBInspectable` attribute?

Comment: Check this answer if you needful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831609/how-to-set-a-max-limit-for-an-ibinspectable-int

Comment: Already check this but doesn't help. if i take IBInspectable type UInt it then min value is 0 in attributes inspector( don't go below 0). i want something like that.

Comment: I also wonder what an inspectable attribute of type "nil"  should be ...

Comment: @MartinR i guess nil refer to the optional types.

Comment: In http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/ it is said that you can use `NSRange`, but that does not work. I *assume* that the Apple documentation is just wrong.

Comment: I believe it too Apple documentation  may be wrong. and i raise this issue at  `bugs.swift.org`  https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4412

Comment: That is for bugs in the Swift language, but your question is about Xcode (the view class can use Swift or Objective-C). You might have to file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/.

Comment: This seems like a bug i mean in storyboard identity inspector under user defined runtime attribute  we are able to add Range attribute( also showing the Nil in the list). but when we add through IBInspectable it doesn't show  user defined runtime attribute. all other are showing.